# Pipe Restrict Contravariant Function

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, contravariance, function-composition

The goal is to construct a Pipe Function that restrict Piping a less derived type than the originally specified (Contravariance), using as few as possible Type Declaration.

Seems that it is possible to construct such Pipe. Scenario below.

```js
  interface Task<A> {
    (): Promise<A>;
  }

  declare const initialValue: Task<boolean>;
  declare const firstLine: (ma: Task<boolean>) => Task<void>;
  declare const secondLine: (ma: Task<void>) => Task<void>; // working
  declare const secondLineProblem: () => Task<void>; // compilation error

  type PipedFunc<ExpectedType, AtualType, Result> = ((
    a: AtualType
  ) => Result) extends (b: any) => any
    ? AtualType extends ExpectedType
      ? (b: AtualType) => Result
      : [
          "Function does not match the expected signature: ",
          (b: ExpectedType) => Result
        ]
    : never;

  type Pipe = {
    <A>(a: A): A;
    <A, B>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B): B;
    <A, B, BArg, C>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B, bc: PipedFunc<B, BArg, C>): C;
    <A, B, BArg, C, CArg, D>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B, bc: PipedFunc<B, BArg, C>, cd: PipedFunc<C, CArg, D>): D;
  };

  export const pipe: Pipe = function(
    a: unknown,
    ab?: Function,
    bc?: Function,
    cd?: Function,
  ): unknown {
    switch (arguments.length) {
      case 1:
        return a;
      case 2:
        return ab!(a);
      case 3:
        return bc!(ab!(a));
      case 4:
        return cd!(bc!(ab!(a)));
    }
    return;
  };

  let task01 = pipe(initialValue, firstLine, secondLine, secondLine);
  let task02 = pipe(initialValue, firstLine, secondLine, secondLineProblem); // Expected compilation Error
  //                                                     ↑
  // Compilation Error - Argument of type '() => Task<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type
  //'["Function does not match the expected signature: ", (b: Task<void>) => Task<void>]'.ts(2345)
```

But this approach makes the use o Type Declaration necessary.

```js
  let sum00 = pipe(10, firstValue => firstValue + 1, (secondValue: number) => secondValue); // works
```

The goal would be to find an approach that would infer the type to the seconds argument below. Without using Type Declaration.

```js
  let sum00 = pipe(10, firstValue => firstValue + 1, secondValue => secondValue); // does not work
  //                                                 ↑
  // Compilation Error - Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
```

Is that possible? It was thinking about using some kind of conditional type in order to infer the Type of `SecondValue`, but it was not possible to arrive at some correct example.

Are there any ways to come-up with this solution in TypeScript?